# IntelliJ: cannot deploy to Google App Engine (Standard)

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea

The IDE complains about no Deployment selected, but from the picture I can't pick one.
[image: No choice available]

I have upgraded IntelliJ to the latest. I am planning to reinstall everything.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be an [artifact displayed](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-google-app-engine.html):

[image: deployment]

Make sure you have a war artifact defined in the [Project Structure | Artifacts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html).

If the issue persists, please [report a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) and attach a sample project to reproduce.

Artifact options available out of the box in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate:

[image: Artifacts]

If you don't see the Web Application options, you need to make sure that all the [plug-ins are enabled](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html). You can also just delete `disabled_plugins.txt` file from the IDE [CONFIG](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) directory and restart the IDE.

Comment: Thanks. If I go in the list of artifacts, there is one marked as type "Other". Options there are JAR, Android Application, JavaFx and Other. It seems an issue with the Google Cloud tools installation. Of course I already uninstalled/reinstalled them.

Comment: Thanks. 
I am looking at some documentation and it seems like web applications require ultimate. I've been using the community version in the past and successfully deployed to Google Cloud before. Maybe this functionality has been removed?

Comment: @Paperino according to [this document](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html), deployment to Google App Engine and other clouds (via plugins) is supported only in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

Comment: @Paperino the [help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-google-app-engine.html) also mentions that IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate [is required](https://i.imgur.com/ogSTE8Y.png).

Comment: Ah, thanks! It used not the be the case before, as I used Community to deploy to GAE just a few months ago...
Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still running into issues:

It actually looks like you are using the Cloud Tools for IntelliJ plugin (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij) and not the App Engine plugin bundled in IDEA Ultimate as in the accepted answer.

You can refer to the following documentation for deployment to the App Engine standard environment:
https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/deploy-std

Also a couple things to check:

- You should have an app engine standard facet
  [image]
- You should have an exploded-war artifact:
  [image]
- Try the following action:
  Tools > Google Cloud Tools > Add App Engine support > Google App Engine Standard and see if this resolves the problem.

If none of this helps, perhaps you can post some screenshots of your artifact / module structure under project settings.

Answer (score 0):

So OK, at the end I was using IntelliJ Community which doesn't support deploying to Google App Engine anymore (although it's bizarre the plugin is available). Apparently one of the latest updates disable whatever minimal support was there, as I was able to deploy to GAE just a few weeks ago.